# QPrinter to .pdf lost colors

Tags: c++, qt, pdf, qprinter

I have a problem with drawing some data to a .pdf.

When I try to print some lines, I lose some colours in the output PDF
It seems strange, I set the pen to red, but the lines are light blue. This issue is replicated exactly the same with other colors.

```
QPrinter printer;
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
printer.setPageOrientation(QPageLayout::Landscape);
printer.setOutputFileName("\img.pdf");
QPainter painter;
painter.begin(&printer);

QPixmap pix(100,100);
for(QVector<QPointF>::iterator it = data->begin(); it != data->end(); ++it){
       it->setY((it->y()*0.02));
}
p.setPen(QPen(Qt::black,1));
p.drawPolyline(data[0].data(),data->size());
painter.drawPixmap(0,100,landscapeWidth,landscapeHeight,pix);

painter.end();
printer.newPage();
```

where data is QVector *.

Do you have any idea, what is the problem with the colors?

Comment: Doesn't your sample code set the pen to `Qt::black`?

Comment: Unfortunale no. It worked, but then it stoped, and now I can't paint black line anymore. It looks strange..

Comment: What I mean is, you say you are getting the wrong color when setting the pen to *red* and this snippet of code uses *black*. Consider [writing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, of course, my mistake. I tried to set pen to black (just thats why I have this in my code:) ), but it doesnt matter which color I choose, I have always problem with this. Its never black, red, green, its always...some kind of blue, it looks like problem with RGB?

Comment: Which QPen constructor are you using? What you have there doesn't seem to correspond to any of the constructors for QPen in the online documentation. I think what you mean is something along the lines of QPen( QBrush( Qt:black ), 1 )